# How to open a terminal from within Atom?

Tags: atom

I'm currently working with Atom, and sometimes I want to open a terminal on the directory my working file is. To do this, I usually have to open the folder in nautilus (right clicking the file in atom) and then I open a terminal on that directory from nautilus (right click).

I wonder if there is a way to open the terminal in the file directory without having to open nautilus first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [this](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal) package, I think it has exactly what you want.

Also, I suggest you to install [term3](https://github.com/Floobits/atom-term3) package. It works great for me, and I just don't have to bother with switching the windows as the terminal window is inside the atom editor.

Good luck!

Comment: I end up installing terminal plus, and it's what I was looking for but tab completion doesn't work, so I might install term3. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I use the [terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus) package to open my terminal from within the Atom text editor. You can see the package in action in this short video clip I made here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFAzqvYoHJs&t=11m14s.

After installing the package, to start the terminal within Atom you can use the GUI or use `cmd-shift-t` on Mac or `ctrl-shift-t` on Windows/Linux to bring up a terminal in the editor. To spawn another terminal session you repeat the previous command.

Comment: Hi! Can you put the essential details from the video in your answer? That way people can follow along a little faster and see what's what. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An option could be [Platformio IDE Terminal](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal) (terminal package for Atom).

Some ot their features are:

- Terminal Naming
- Color Coding
- Sorting
- Insert selected text

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of terminal packages you can use in Atom. The packages which I recommend are :-

1. [terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus)
2. [atom-terminal-panel](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal-panel)
3. [term3](https://atom.io/packages/term3)
4. [atom-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal)